# How to write this quote in a motivating way, for a poster?

Tags: grammar, sentence

"Success doesn't come to you, you go to it!"

Does this sound right? I feel that something is wrong with it, but I, as an ESL can't really figure what is wrong. How to properly phrase this sentence?

Please tell me if such questions shouldn't be asked on StackExchange English. I am new to the website.

Comment: Do you mean [Hang in there, baby](http://advertising.i5publishing.com/iconic-cats-the-hang-in-there-baby-poster/)?

Comment: "Success doesn't come to you, you go TO it!"

Comment: You go to it or you go for it. You cannot just go it. The verb cannot be transitive in this meaning. That is decidedly ungrammatical.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. re: "Please tell me if such questions shouldn't be asked on StackExchange English. I am new to the website." Sadly, the answer is that "How can I improve this sentence?" kind of questions are not dealt with on ELU. Please see the FAQ at http://english.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: See also: [ell.se] which may interest you as an ESL student.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the "to". That was a typo from me.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> Success doesn't come looking for you, you have to go for it!

There's a double meaning to the second half of the sentence - in addition to meaning "you have to actively search for success" (implied by the context), the phrase "go for it" also means to strongly commit to something. This usage should be familiar to native English speakers, but may not be obvious to non-native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with different wording.

> Don't wait for success to come to you. Go out there and seize it!